# Different methods using Functors/Delegates in c#

Tags: c#, delegates, functor

I have a method that I call multiple times, but each time a different method with a different signature is called from inside.

```
public void MethodOne()
{
//some stuff

*MethodCall();

//some stuff

}
```

So `MethodOne` is called multiple times, each time with a different `*MethodCall()`. What I'm trying to do is something like this :

```
public void MethodOne(Func<> MethodCall)
{
//some stuff

*MethodCall;

//some stuff

}
```

but the Methods that are called each have a different return type and different parameters. Is there a way to do this using Functors? If not, how would I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about `*` in C#? Besides, how are you going to call a function which requires parameters without actually supplying them?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create a SuperMethod.  You might consider looking into your design a bit more.  If methods have different input *and* different output, they probably shouldn't be grouped together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best bet would be to use the non-generic `Action` type (or `MethodInvoker` would be the same), i.e.

```
public void MethodOne(Action callback)
{
    //some stuff

    if(callback != null) callback();

    //some stuff
}
```

From this you can call any method by wrapping it at the caller, i.e.

```
MethodOne(SimpleMethod); // SimpleMethod has no parameters and returns void
MethodOne(() => MoreComplexMethod(1, "abc")); // this one returns void
MethodOne(() => { MethodThatReturnsSomething(12); }); // anything you like
```

etc

Comment: how to return the result in this case?

Comment: @CuongLe: `int res = 0; MethodOne(() => { res = MethodThatReturnsSomething(12); });`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a function which requires parameters without supplying them, so the answer is "no, not possible"

Also, maybe you want the following:

```
void MethodOne(Action a)
{
    // some stuff
    a();
    // some stuff
}

... // somewhere in the code
MethodOne((Action)(() => { DoSomethingOther(1, 2, 3); }));
MethodOne((Action)(() => { DoSomethingEvenDifferent(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); }));
```

Comment: What stops OP from 'computing the arguments' during 'some stuff'?

Comment: @Amit: basically, the signature of the function: he doesn't know if `a` does have arguments in reality. If the user needs just to call "something", he definitely doesn't know what the arguments are or may possibly be.

Answer (score 1):

Every delegate in .Net is an instance of a class derived from [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y22acf51.aspx). So if you really wish to pass 'any' delegate to a method, you can pass it as `Delegate`

To invoke it, you need to use its [DynamicInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx) method.

```
public void MethodOne(Delegate MethodCall)
{
//some stuff

//Assuming you now have the required parameters
//or add params object[] args to the signature of this method
object res = MethodCall.DynamicInvoke(args); //args is object[] representing the parameters

//some stuff
}
```

But this is not recommended as `DynamicInvoke` is slow and it does not offer any compile time safety. Probably you should revisit your design.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically not possible. You could make `MethodOne` generic for the return type, and use a lambda that closes over its outside block instead of parameters:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int parameterSubst = 1;
    int result = MethodOne<int>(() => parameterSubst);
    string result2 = MethodOne<string>(() =>
    {
        string s = parameterSubst.ToString();
        s += "foo";
        return s;
    });
}

static T MethodOne<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    return function();
}
```

As you can see, `parameterSubst` is used in the passed `Func<T>`s, but not as a parameter.